# Number density contours in Python

Tags: python, plot, contour

I'm trying to reproduce this plot in python with little luck:

[image]

It's a simple number density contour currently done in SuperMongo.  I'd like to drop it in favor of Python but the closest I can get is:

[image]

which is by using hexbin().  How could I go about getting the python plot to resemble the SuperMongo one?  I don't have enough rep to post images, sorry for the links.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6):

Example simple contour plot from a fellow SuperMongo => python sufferer:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.interactive(True)
fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

# generate input data; you already have that
x1 = np.random.normal(0,10,100000)
y1 = np.random.normal(0,7,100000)/10.
x2 = np.random.normal(-15,7,100000)
y2 = np.random.normal(-10,10,100000)/10.
x=np.concatenate([x1,x2])
y=np.concatenate([y1,y2])

# calculate the 2D density of the data given
counts,xbins,ybins=np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=100,normed=LogNorm())
# make the contour plot
plt.contour(counts.transpose(),extent=[xbins.min(),xbins.max(),
    ybins.min(),ybins.max()],linewidths=3,colors='black',
    linestyles='solid')
plt.show()
```

produces a nice contour plot.

The contour function offers a lot of fancy adjustments, for example let's set the levels by hand:

```
plt.clf()
mylevels=[1.e-4, 1.e-3, 1.e-2]
plt.contour(counts.transpose(),mylevels,extent=[xbins.min(),xbins.max(),
    ybins.min(),ybins.max()],linewidths=3,colors='black',
    linestyles='solid')
plt.show()
```

producing this plot:[image: contour plot with adjusted levels]

And finally, in SM one can do contour plots on linear and log scales, so I spent a little time trying to figure out how to do this in matplotlib. Here is an example when the y points need to be plotted on the log scale and the x points still on the linear scale:

```
plt.clf()
# this is our new data which ought to be plotted on the log scale
ynew=10**y
# but the binning needs to be done in linear space
counts,xbins,ybins=np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=100,normed=LogNorm())
mylevels=[1.e-4,1.e-3,1.e-2]
# and the plotting needs to be done in the data (i.e., exponential) space
plt.contour(xbins[:-1],10**ybins[:-1],counts.transpose(),mylevels,
    extent=[xbins.min(),xbins.max(),ybins.min(),ybins.max()],
    linewidths=3,colors='black',linestyles='solid')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

This produces a plot which looks very similar to the linear one, but with a nice vertical log axis, which is what was intended: [image: contour plot with log axis]

Comment: Why there transpose is taken in counts? What will be the difference if we just use counts use of counts.transpose()

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [matplotlib's contour plot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour)?

Comment: That's the first thing I looked at, but it requires an equation that describes the surface.

Comment: @Robert, I don't think it needs an equation to do the surface...I've used it with just points.  What about something like this? http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html

Comment: that code requires a z parameter: 

z = x*np.exp(-x**2-y**2).

I don't have anything like that for my data.

Comment: @Robert: z is just the data array that you want to contour. You must have that!

Comment: Hrm, how does one translate a number density into an array to contour though?

Comment: Your data seems a lot like 2D matrices where each pixel is the height. For example, if it were a map, the position of a point would be latitude and longitude, and the value would be its elevation. If you have that in the array `a`, simply use `matplotlib.pyplot.contour(a)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't view yours images. Do you mean something like [this](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/en/2d_plots.html)? It was done by [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) -- GPL plotting library, which have Python interface too. And you can use arbitrary data arrays as input (including numpy's one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.histogram2d to get a number density distribution of your array. 
Try this example:
http://micropore.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/2d-density-plot-or-2d-histogram/

Comment: you should copy the code here, and keep the link as reference.